# Interaction term btw. binary and continuous variable - dropping the intercept?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, interpretation, categorical-encoding, intercept

I run a linear regression with many dummy variables (in total 10). Thus to avoid the dummy variable trap, I dropped the intercept and included all dummy variables. 
Now I'd like to have a look at the `interaction` term between a continuous and a binary variable. Can I do so, even if the intercept is not included in the regression? What would the interpretation be?
And further on:
If I include the interaction term, itself is not significant, while the coefficient of one of the 2 variables is now statistically significant.
Here a brief example to visualize it:

```
y = b1 X1 + b2 X2, where X2 is binary
```

The coefficient X1 is not significant, neither is X2

```
y = b1 X1 + b2 X2 + b3 (X1 * X2), where X2 is binary
```

The coefficient `X1` is now significant, `b2` and `b3` are not statistically significant.

What does that imply? How can I decide to include the interaction term or not?